# await Bcrypt.compare is still true even after an hash update on database when comparing to previous plain value

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, bcrypt, sequelize-typescript

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour while using bcrypt to compare a plain value and a hash.

I have this method :

```
async refreshToken(userId: number, refreshToken: string): Promise<any> {
    const user: User = await this.userService.findByIdWithAuthInfo(userId);
    
    if (!user?.authInfo?.refreshToken) {
      throw new ImATeapotException('You cannot do that.');
    }

    console.log(refreshToken);
    console.log(user.authInfo.refreshToken);
    const isMatch: boolean = await bcrypt.compare(refreshToken, user.authInfo.refreshToken);

    if (!isMatch) {
      throw new ImATeapotException('You cannot do that.');
    }

    return this.generateTokenPairAndUpdateAuthInfo(user);
  }
```

User entity has an AuthInfo which has a refreshToken, which is the hash of a token. My problem is:
when calling the `refreshToken()` method, even though the hash stored in the databased doesn't represent the hash of the refreshToken method parameter, the isMatch value is `true`.

When i `console.log(user.authInfo.refreshToken)` it is the latest updated token hash, and `refreshToken` string parameter is an older token.
But why does the bcrypt.compare returns true even though the refreshToken parameter is a previous token which hash is not stored anymore and has been replaced by a new hash of a different token ?

here are the method used for updating database entry: (values are correctly updated):

```
  private async hashData(data: string): Promise<string> {
    return await bcrypt.hash(
      data,
      this.config.get<number>("security.saltRounds")
    );
  }

  private async generateToken(id: number, username: string, refresh: boolean): Promise<string> {
    return this.jwtService.signAsync(
      {
        sub: id,
        username: username,
      },
      {
        secret: this.config.get<string>(
          refresh ? "security.jwtRefreshSecret" : "security.jwtSecret"
        ),
        expiresIn: this.config.get<number>(
          refresh ? "security.refreshTokenDuration" : "security.accessTokenDuration"
        ),
      }
    );
  }

  private async generateTokenPairAndUpdateAuthInfo(user: User): Promise<any> {
    const accessToken = await this.generateToken(user.id, user.username, false);
    const refreshToken = await this.generateToken(user.id, user.username, true);

    await this.authInfoService.updateTokens(
      user.authInfoId,
      await this.hashData(accessToken),
      await this.hashData(refreshToken),
    );

    return { accessToken, refreshToken };
  }
```

the `authInfoService.updateTokens()` method is only calling the repository update method via a service. May be the problem could come from the fact that i'm not an expert in async dev but I don't think so as database gets correctly updated.

the dependencies versions i'm using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.3.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.3.3",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.31.1",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.1",
    "@types/js-yaml": "^4.0.5",
    "@types/node": "18.16.12",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.35",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.15",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0"
  },
```

What I have tried =>

Pass a raw string value in the bcrypt.compare such as 'tototititata' => returns `false` as expected
Pass an older token in bcrypt.compare() and thus comparing it with a different token's hash => returns `true` and i do not understand why.

I mean isnt the purpose of a hash to (almost) always provide a different hash as long as the input value is different ?

Could it be a cache problem or stuff i'm not awared of because of my limited knowledge of async programming ?

So has I said previously, my main question is :

Why does the bcrypt.compare returns true even though the refreshToken parameter is a previous token which hash is not stored anymore and has been replaced by a new hash of a different token ?

Comment: `bcrypt.compare` is used ONLY for password checking, as it check plainText against hash of it. 
What you want to do is probably validate if the given token is still valid, or even just plain `===` compare the hashes